# Different Explain Plans in SQL Developer vs Explain Plan for command

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-execution-plan

When I get the explain plan of the following query, I see that, both table has full table scan.

```
SELECT *
  FROM employees e,
       departments d
 WHERE e.employee_id = d.manager_id;
```

Here is the explain plan I got with the explain plan command. [by EXPLAIN PLAN FOR command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7qgk.jpg)
[image]

https://i.hizliresim.com/JZdB2o.jpg
https://hizliresim.com/JZdB2o https://pasteboard.co/HO9ARcl.jpg

But, if I get the explain plan of the same query with SQL developer, I see a significantly different explain plan.
Especially, it writes table access full at the buttom but over it, it writes table access by index rowid.

Here is the explain plan I got from the SQL Developer. [by SQL Developer Explain Plan button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1y10.jpg)
[image]

https://i.hizliresim.com/DYoYbv.jpg
https://hizliresim.com/DYoYbv https://pasteboard.co/HO9BxfA.jpg

My question is, could anyone explain the **explain plan of the SQL developer** step by step? And why SQL Developer and explain plan command generate different explain plans?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several different ways to get the plan for a query in SQL Developer.

Explain Plan
[image]

Cached Plan
[image]

DBMS_XPLAN
[image]

Which method are you using? You've cropped your picture such that we can't tell if this is a cached plan from V$SQL_PLAN or an Explain Plan.

Now, onto the crux of your question - do not use Explain Plan. It can be unreliable. It shows you a plan that could be run - it doesn't show you the actual plan that was or will be used.

Also note this in your plan output -

> -- this is an adaptive plan

Adaptive Plans in Oracle Database 12c allow runtime changes to execution plans. It generally happens because the statistics are lying to the optimizer. The DB thinks there are 5 rows but when it goes to read them from an index or a table, it finds 50,000 rows instead. So the database goes, to heck with this, we're going to do something else.

So my advice -

Collect statistics on your two tables:

```
BEGIN
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname => 'HR', tabname => 'EMPLOYEES', estimate_percent => 100);
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname => 'HR', tabname => 'DEPARTMENTS', estimate_percent => 100);
END;
```

Then, run your plans again. Except this time, don't use EXPLAIN PLAN FOR - use the 2nd or 3rd option I show above,.

Comment: Hi Jeff. Thanks

Comment: Hi Jeff. 
Thanks for your interest.
The first explain plan is by EXPLAIN PLAN FOR "Query" and DBMS_XPLAN package.
The second one is by the SQL Developer's explain plan button (F10). Autotrace also returns the same result.
But the problem is, unlike the dbms_xplan, sql developer shows employees table with both index scan and full scan, however, in dbms_xplan, it shows only full scan.
For NLS parameters: I do them both in SQL Developer. So the same session.
For the images: I added with some new ways, too.
I'll be waiting for your response.
Best regards

Comment: @oramas i fixed your question up and amended my answer

Comment: Hi Jeff. 
Thank you for your interest and effort. 

Even if I get the same execution plans via cached plan, autotrace, etc, they all have the same explain plan. 

The problem is, in the graphical view of SQL Developer explain plan, it is different. Even in your images, they are different.

If I get the explain plan with the code below, I get full table scans only.
select * from table (dbms_xplan.display_cursor('g7qhw7dd38ngf'));

But if I see the cached plan with SQL Developer Explain Plan button, like you showed, I see some unique scan, index scan, etc.

Comment: So If you have time, would you explain the explain plan of cached plan that you taken with SQL Developer? Because it seems different to me. There are some grey areas, why there is an index by rowid to employees table, why it writes nested loops for two times while there is no nested loop operation in the dbms_xplan and why they are colored grey, etc?
If you can help me to clear them out, I'll be really appreciate for that.
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the artifact of the adaptive plan; you are actually seeing both versions of the plan in the output. The greyed out lines are the version of the plan that were not executed.